# How to get moodle quiz questions details in to an array?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

Is there any option in moodle to get complete list of quiz **Question id, Question name, Question content (description), options, selected option, score (min, max, raw)** as an `array()` ?

These are the details I can get from Quiz event

```
$course  = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $event->courseid));
$quiz    = $DB->get_record('quiz', array('id' => $event->quizid));
$cm      = get_coursemodule_from_id('quiz', $event->cmid, $event->courseid);
$attempt = $DB->get_record('quiz_attempts', array('id' => $event->attemptid));
```

Could you please give any advice please.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I need to get Question id and Question name (and Quiz ID), so I'll appreciate if you can share if you found this out?

Comment: @Zarah Please check answer at the bottom. Let me know if you have trouble on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method used like this

```
// Quiz Question attempt$table = "question";
$questionsattempts = $DB - > get_records('question_attempts', array('questionusageid' = > $attempt - > uniqueid));

foreach($questionsattempts as $value) {
    $questionsattempt = $value;
    // QuestionID is passed as parameter to this routine as we are producing a submit block for each question in turn
    //$questionid = $value->questionid;
}
```

**Question id:-** `'id' =>  $CFG->wwwroot.'/question/preview.php?id='.$questionsattempt->questionid`